# creating non-uniform spaces on game map

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, voronoi

I need advice on creating a game map. I need to create 1400 spaces on the map. I'm imagining that each space will be one of 10 different sizes - for example, their will be a dozen that are 'size-10', forty that are 'size-9', etc., with a couple hundred at the smallest-sizes (this is data-driven). There will also be a neutral space in the center (probably a bit larger than all others). I'd like to place these regions on the game space randomly, but there should be no overlap, and no space between them. It doesn't matter if the total space is a rectangle. I really like [this effort](http://www-cs-students.stanford.edu/~amitp/game-programming/polygon-map-generation/), though it's very out of my league, but it led me to research voronoi tesselations and find a [javascript implementation](http://philogb.github.com/blog/2010/02/12/voronoi-tessellation/) that I somewhat understand, but all examples I've seen use random points as origins and I'm looking for a more custom result as I've described above, so this might not be the way to go. --- Anyway, I'm open to any suggestions. Please note that I'm a designer rather than a coder, but am coding my own prototypes so any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This seems similar to the [Knapsack Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem) if I understand it correctly. But, instead of optimizing, you are only looking for a single solution. This is actually a pretty difficult problem to try and solve, both in terms of time complexity and in terms of just getting something reasonable (i.e. finishes in reasonable time) working. [This](http://rjlipton.wordpress.com/2010/02/05/a-2010-algorithm-for-the-knapsack-problem/) is an interesting post about it (although he deals with optimization) - with a little work, you could furnish a good-enough algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly what you want to achieve is the so called path directed subdivision tree or [quadtree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree). The specific of this algorithm is to divide recursively a rectangular two dimensional space into four smaller pieces called quadrants or quads. The regions may be square or rectangular, or may have arbitrary shapes.

If you need a real example for studying the code you can have as a starting point this experiment created in Actionscript, but this can be well translated into Javascript too: http://wonderfl.net/c/fLVs

Another possibility would be [Delaunay triangulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delaunay_triangulation) with the control points selected manually, because if understand correctly you do not want to scatter the points randomly. Maybe this link will help: http://neoformix.com/2012/DelaunayImages2.html

I hope these helps!